# SQL - How to extract a 4 digit number between two underscores in a cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below fields where I need to extract the 4 digit number in between two underscores where if what is in between two underscores is ONLY a 4 digit number?
If there isn't then there should be a null

These are examples:

```
    Cell
    HV_August 2019_Integrated EM_DAM_3183_PROS_GEN_20110919
    COO_COOL COOL Newsletter_4868_RAM_20140327
    PIP_PIP TACTICAL_PIP TACTICAL LOOK_4877_PIP_NON_RIP_20140326
    IPWarming_LALA_20101017-Split(2)
    toomuch_12345_toomuch
```

and
I expect

```
    ID
    3183
    4868
    4877
    NULL
    NULL
```

As you can see, the 4 digit code could be anywhere within the cell, it would be after the 2nd underscore or 3rd underscore etc..

How would I get around this one?

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen when there is more than one 4 digit number in a single row

Answer (score 5):

Try this is out.

```
DECLARE @cell_1 VARCHAR(500) = 'HV_August 2019 Integrated EM_DAM_3183_PROS_GEN_20110919 COO_COOL';
DECLARE @cell_2 VARCHAR(500) = 'COOL_Newsletter_4868_RAM_20140327 PIP_PIP TACTICAL_PIP TACTICAL';
DECLARE @cell_3 VARCHAR(500) = 'LOOK_4877_PIP_NON_RIP_20140326';

--In PATINDEX, underscore is a special character so you have to put them in brackets
    --Then the [0-9] represent any number
SELECT SUBSTRING(cell,PATINDEX('%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%',cell) + 1,4) AS digit_code
FROM
(
    SELECT @cell_1 AS cell
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @cell_2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @cell_3
) A;
```

Results:

```
digit_code
----------
3183
4868
4877
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
;with CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 'HV_August 2019_Integrated EM_DAM_3183_PROS_GEN_20110919' Col1 UNION ALL
        SELECT 'COO_COOL COOL Newsletter_4868_RAM_20140327' UNION ALL
        SELECT 'PIP_PIP TACTICAL_PIP TACTICAL LOOK_4877_PIP_NON_RIP_20140326'
    )
    SELECT Col1, 
    SUBSTRING(Col1, NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[_][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][_]%',Col1)
               + 1,0),4) data 
    FROM CTE
```